# Changing the keyboard layout to the new Hebrew standard

Tags: windows, keyboard

A couple of months ago the Standards Institution of Israel published a new standard for keyboards in Hebrew.

How do I tell Windows 10 that I want to use the new layout.?

[image]

I already tried going to the keyboard section in Windows 10 and changing the layout from Hebrew to Hebrew(standard) but it seems to make no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new layout is not shipped with the current versions of Windows, and you will need to install the layout on your computer.

Site offering the new layout for download is http://mikladot.com/

The new layout will be available only after restart (although the installation won't ask you to restart your computer)